# rejectionhandled not firing

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to use `rejectionhandled` but I can't get it to fire. The code below should work based on all the documnation I could find. I register a listener for `rejectionhandled` then reject a promise and catch it. In both chrome and firefox with the flag enabled 'testing' is logged but not 'rejected'. What am I missing?

```
window.addEventListener("rejectionhandled", e => console.log("rejected"), false);
new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 1000)).catch(err => console.error("testing"))
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have the latest versions installed? That event is quite new and not yet well supported.

Comment: What [browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/rejectionhandled_event#Browser_compatibility) are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`rejectionhandled` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/rejectionhandled_event) doesn't fire on every handled rejection, it only fires on rejections that were not handled at first (causing [`unhandledrejection` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event)) but then did subsequently get a handler attached.

The events are fired from the HTML implementation of the [implementation-defined `HostPromiseRejectionTracker`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-host-promise-rejection-tracker) in the ECMAScript spec, whose note says

> HostPromiseRejectionTracker is called in two scenarios:
>
> - When a promise is rejected without any handlers, it is called with its operation argument set to "reject".
> - When a handler is added to a rejected promise for the first time, it is called with its operation argument set to "handle".

Comment: The MDN documentation needs some improvement unfortunately.