# `rejectionhandled` event is not firing after the rejected promise rejection handler is attached

Tags: javascript, frontend, dom-events

The `rejectionhandled` event should trigger after the `unhandledrejection` event handler attaches the rejection handler (`catch()`) to the promise but it doesn't

In node.js we have the same `unhandledRejection` and `rejectionHandled` events that works fine

What am I missing?

```
onunhandledrejection = function(ev){                       // event property triggered as expected (promise ha a missing rejection handler)
    console.log( 'promise has no rejection handler!' );
    ev.promise                                             // the promise that has no rejection handler 
        .catch(err => console.log(err))                    // attaching the rejection handler to the promise  (THIS SHOULD TRIGGER THE rejectionhandler event)
}

onrejectionhandled = function(ev){                         // NOT triggered 
    console.log( 'rejection handled!' );
}

addEventListener('rejectionhandled', function(ev){         // NOT triggered 
    console.log( 'rejection handled!' );
})


Promise.reject("I'm rejected!");                           // rejected promise without rejection handler
```

Comment: I'd guess that the unhandledRejection event gets run at the end of the first event loop iteration after the promise rejection, thus the rejectionhandled precondition "error handler was attached to it (using promise.catch(), for example) later than one turn of the Node.js event loop." does not apply.

Answer (score 2):

By [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57261820) and the spec content mentioned in it, it seems that if an rejection was not caught in the current event loop, but caught in any later event loop, then in that event loop, `rejectionhandled` will be triggered.

```js
window.addEventListener("rejectionhandled", (ev) => {
    console.log("rejectionhandled ev.promise:", ev.promise);
    console.log("rejectionhandled ev.reason:", ev.reason);
});

let p = Promise.reject("oops");

// setTimeout callback will be called in next event loop
setTimeout(() => {
    p.catch((err) => {console.log("handle rejection: " + err)});
});

// output：
// handle rejection: oops
// rejectionhandled ev.promise: Promise {<rejected>: 'oops'}
// rejectionhandled ev.reason: oops
```