# How do Promise.then and "rejectionhandled" differ in their execution order in the next run of event loop?

Tags: javascript, html, promise, runtime

Consider example1:

```js
var prom1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Prom 1 executed");
    reject("Rejected");
  }, 2000);
});

console.log("Before Prom 1");  

window.addEventListener("rejectionhandled", function(event) {
  console.log("Handled Rejection"); //never triggers
});

window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function(e) {
  console.log("unhandledrejection");  
  prom1.then(null, function(err) {
    console.log("Caught error");
  });
});
```

In this scenario `rejectionhandled` does not trigger. Now consider example2:

```js
var prom1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Prom 1 executed");
    reject("Rejected");
  }, 2000);
});

console.log("Before Prom 1");  

window.addEventListener("rejectionhandled", function(event) {
  console.log("Handled Rejection"); //never triggers
});

window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function(e) {
  console.log("unhandledrejection");  
  setTimeout(function() {
    prom1.then(null, function(err) {
      console.log("Caught error");
    });
  }, 0);
});
```

Now in this instance `rejectionhandled` did run. I know it has something to do with microtask/macrotask/event-loop. I know there are similar questions on SO, but I can't seem to apply that explanation here. Probably the explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57261820/3429430 should mean that  whenever the promise is caught **within unhandledrejection's handler** it is not considered as attached **after** unhandledrejection's handler's execution.

Answer (score 1):

That's because in HTML, at the step 5.4 of the [notify about rejected promises](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#notify-about-rejected-promises) algorithm, it is asked that

> 4. If *p*'s [[PromiseIsHandled]] internal slot is false, add *p* to *settings object*'s [outstanding rejected promises weak set](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#outstanding-rejected-promises-weak-set).

And in the [`HostPromiseRejectionTracker(promise, "handle")`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#the-hostpromiserejectiontracker-implementation) algorithm, at step 5.2 it's asked that

> 2. If *settings object*'s [outstanding rejected promises weak set](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#outstanding-rejected-promises-weak-set) does not contain *promise*, then return.

In the first case, after the event has been dispatched, *p*  (a.k.a *promise*), has been handled, you did add a `.then(success, failure)` handler and its `[[PromiseIsHandled]]` internal slot is now `true`. So that *p* won't make it to the "outstanding rejected promises weak set", and when the JS engine will call the `HostPromiseRejectionTracker(promise, "handle")` operation, it will early exit at the quoted 5.4 step.

In the second case however, when the event has been dispatched its `[[PromiseIsHandled]]` internal slot is still `false`, and when the `HostPromiseRejectionTracker(promise, "handle")` operation is called, it will make it to the end of the algorithm until it fires the *rejectionhandled* event.

So indeed, we could rephrase the other answer to say

> it only fires on rejections that were not handled at first (causing *unhandledrejection* events) but then did subsequently get a handler attached *[after the* unhandledrejection *event got dispatched]*.